# Adafruit CCS811 Air Quality Sensor

Tags: adafruit

in my arduino project I use the Adafruit CCS811 Air Quality Sensor Breakout - VOC and eCO2, I need the references and sizes of these components, knowing that I have found the electrical diagram but the values and references are not clear as you see in the photo.
Link to the sensor: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ccs811-air-quality-sensor/overview
Thank you in advance for your help.[image]

Comment: What exactly is not clear? Do you need to know the physical size of each component? You can look at the PCB layout and then lookup the components with the corresponding packages. Their datasheets also include their size. Or do you want to know something different?

Comment: And wouldn't a question about an adafruit sensor be better suited for the Adafruit forum?